# Cant find where to start a new project

Tags: visual-studio-code

I have recently installed Visual Studio Code (version 1.44.2) and I cant figure out how to start a new project.

I've looked through tutorials and articles on how to do so, but most all of these sources mention a clear button that states *Start a new project*. I cannot find this button on the welcome page, or anywhere else for that matter.

Nothing seems to work, and the *Create new folder* button only brings up a text document. But when I select a language—using a small button in the bottom right hand corner—and try to debug, run, or compile the program the *Run* and *Debug* buttons are grayed out.

Comment: Have you installed the Extension for the desired language from the Marketplace?

Comment: I believe so. C# and .Net Core tools

Comment: Installed the .NET Core SDK as well?https://dotnet.microsoft.com/download

Comment: Have a look: https://code.visualstudio.com/docs/languages/dotnet

Comment: I have downloaded it, and I looked through the last link and only got an access is denied when running the cmd prompt commands even in when I tried it in the admin console.

Comment: "I've looked through tutorials and articles on how to do so, but most all of these sources mention a clear button that states Start a new project." — Please cite one so we know the context you are working with.

Comment: "I've looked through tutorials and articles on how to do so" Which tutorials and articles are you looking at? Are you sure they are for Visual Studio **Code** and not Visual Studio?

Answer (score 1):

You might have confused Visual Studio (an IDE) with Visual Studio Code (more of a code editor).
The two are not the same thing.
I had the same problem in this tutorial for example:
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/nuget/quickstart/install-and-use-a-package-in-visual-studio

I simply could not find the "new project" button in visual studio code.

Answer (score 0):

The original post tags which were edited from [visual-studio](/questions/tagged/visual-studio) to [visual-studio-code](/questions/tagged/visual-studio-code) and the reference to a *Start a new project* button seems to indicate some confusion between those two applications. Maybe those tutorials were intended for [visual-studio](/questions/tagged/visual-studio) not [visual-studio-code](/questions/tagged/visual-studio-code).

I've just tried the following [simple tutorial](https://learn.microsoft.com/fr-fr/dotnet/core/tutorials/with-visual-studio-code) and it works as intended. Perhaps it could help you figure out what you have to do.

Basically, all you have to do is:

1. Create a new folder for you project, let it be empty for now.
2. Right-click on it to choose "Open with Code" in context menu (if your OS lack such option, you can simply type *code <name_of_the_new_folder>* in your favorite shell).
   Once vscode is up, choose menu 'Terminal > New Terminal'
3. In the newly opened terminal in vscode, type 'dotnet new console'
   you should now have two files and a folder in your project folder: `Program.cs`, `dotnet.csproj` and `obj`
4. Open the explorer view (<kbd>ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>shift</kbd>+<kbd>E</kbd>) and open the file `Program.cs`.

This should trigger the download of a few things depending of what your installation already include.
A new folder `bin` should appear in your project folder.

At the same time, a window should appear at the bottom right of vscode window saying:
*Required assets to build and debug are missing from 'dotnet'. Add them?*
Click *Yes*.

Once done, you should have a new folder: `.vscode`. In there you'll find a `launch.json` file which contains some directives that enable the run *button* you find in the 'Run view' (<kbd>ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>shift</kbd>+<kbd>D</kbd>).

5. Clicking this *run button* will start your application in debugging mode.
6. Choose menu 'Run > Run Without Debugging' to just run your application. Alternatively, you can use `dotnet run`.

Comment: There is no such a "Open with Code" option in VS Code as in your point 2, at least on linux

Comment: @aless80, if your distribution is using nautilus there is a solution [here](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1049111/add-open-with-vscode-to-context-menu-in-ubuntu). The same can probably be done for other file managers. As a last resort, i've added the shell way to achieve the same.

Answer (score 0):

You need to save the file with the extension of the language you are using (.py for Python, .cpp for C++, and so on). Also, go to the marketplace and download plugins related to that language. How to actually run the code depends on the plugin itself, so make sure to check the documentation. However, if you need to just run snippets of code for interpreted languages, you can use the terminal (ctrl + shift + `). For that, I would recommend setting up a keyboard shortcut for "Run Selected Text In Active Terminal" in the settings at the bottom left.

Answer (score 0):

Visual Studio Code does not have a "Start a new project" option anywhere that I know. Instead, you create a new folder and place your code files in that project. You should be very careful when reading tutorials. Be sure you are not looking at ones Visual Studio Code not for Visual Studio. These are two different things.